# Browser-specific behavior with %-sized floats. Reasons and solutions?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a series of quadratic divs in a floating environment. Their width is set to 19.5% of the parent element with a margin of .25%. Their 1:1 aspect ratio is ensured by scaling a quadratic image to 100% of the floating div's width:

```
div.item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 19.5%;
    margin: .25%;
}

div.item img {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now what I get is rows with five floating divs each, spanning the whole width of the parent div.

What I would like to do is increase the size of the very first float to cover the same area as 2x2 of the other floats, setting its width to 2*19.5% + 2*.25% = 39.5%.

Having done that, testing in two browsers, chromium and firefox, both on Linux. I get different results.

Chromium renders the case as expected, one big image with two rows of three divs each on its right side, followed by rows with five divs each.

Firefox however displays three rows with only three divs to the right of the big one before having five-item rows. The two items below the big one are effectively missing, just as if the height of it was a little too big (not visibly though). Setting the size of the big one to 39.49% works but while the difference is probably not visible in most cases, it's a pretty dirty hack.

Have a look at the testing site here: http://www.schattensaiten.net/sm62/live

Any ideas what could be the reason for firefox' behavior and how to get around this problem?

EDIT: I just finally found a firefox window-size where it does look correct, so it probably has something to do with rounding errors when scaling the images by percentage. I have so far not found a case where it was not working in Chrome, so Chrome seems to be more forgiving about that.
Still, I'd be highly interested in a working solution that does not force me to give up my approach of the site dynamically adjusting to use the full browser size. I hate fixed-width layouts. I want to present my images as large as I can on any given screen.

Comment: Definitely rounding errors. Breaks in Chrome for Mac @ 1583px width.

Comment: Thank you @Pavlo, good to know. Maybe it's best then to abandon floating and rework the layout using absolute positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a viable solution, keeping the simple float layout. Adding "clear: both" or "clear: left" to the first item of the third row ensures that the complete row is moved down below the large image.

In some cases, having a very close look, it can still be seen that the margin below the large image is a pixel smaller than below the other three images but if you don't know, you probably wouldn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

try placing a element inside your box with the margin.

```
.item{width: 20%;}
.inside{margin: 5px;}
```

[Like my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LF3TV/)

Comment: W3Schools says for margin-top %: "Specifies a top margin in percent of the width of the containing element". So this should be ok. Your suggestion will not work for the given case anyway. If the top/bottom margin is not .25% but has a fixed value, it is not ensured that the larger image is exactly two rows high.

Comment: how about you use width 20% and then put at box inside with 5px margin? then it would be the same everywhere.

Comment: @inVader You shouldn't refer to W3Schools.

Comment: Sorry @Pavlo, but why?

Comment: @inVader Inaccurate information, vastly considered as an unreliable source: http://www.w3fools.com/ Use MDN or Webplatform.org

Comment: This is definately less prone to error as there are only two different percentages, 20% and 40% instead of 19.5%, 39.5% and .25%, still I'm not sure if in some rare cases this could still result in rounding errors. But I think your solution should even allow for a dynamic margin in percent, it does not have to be fixed at 5px or something. I will definately give this a closer look.

Comment: You should be able to use percent margins inside the div, although you need to double the .bigger-element.

Comment: I've tested it now on the real-life example. Does not work flawlessly, there are still rounding errors that sometimes cause the two elements below the big one to be moved to the right.